# BASH - Quick networksetup command Q

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the below command that fails when I run it through a bash script but If I copy each echoed statement and paste them in a terminal it works...

```
networksetup -listallntworkservices | while read line; do networksetup -setautoproxy '"'$line'"' http://etc...
```

I ideally only want to run the above command for network services that have "Ethernet" or "Wi-fi" in the name.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using that quoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know what are the input of your command :
Try change `'"'$line'"'` by `"$line"` or `"'$line'"`.

To avoid shell expansion in the case variable contains spaces always double quote variables when passing an argument to a command.

If double quotes are needed inside variable, this should work: `"\"$line\""`

To filter lines matching Ethernet or Wi-fi

```
networksetup -listallntworkservices |
  while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (Ethernet|Wi-fi) ]]; then
      networksetup -setautoproxy "$line" http://etc.
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Duh...."$line" worked just fine. How can I only issue the command for "Ethernet" or "Wi-fi" ?

Comment: you can use bash regexp `if [[ $line =~ (Ethernet|Wi-fi) ]]; then ...; fi` in this case double quotes are not needed because double brakets are keywords.

Comment: Why? plesae give input and output required : replace networksetup command by echo to see how if works